# Linked list clear and insert function in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have been struggling with Pointers and frankly C++ for a few weeks now. I had a project for school that I gave up on (the deadline has passed). Even though I can't turn it in I still want to complete it for practice and I am stuck with my clear method but there could be other ways I should be doing some of this.

.h file

```
using namespace std;

template < typename T >   // Forward declaration of the SimpList class
class SimpList;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Definition of class Node<T>
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

template < typename T >
class Node                 // Node class for the SimpList class
{
  private:

    // Constructors

    Node () { next = 0; }  // default constructor

    // Complete the definition inline

    Node ( const T &initItem, Node<T> *ptr ) {
        value=initItem;
        next=ptr;
    }

    // Data members

    T           value;   // Node data item
    Node        *next;  // Pointer to the next node

  friend class SimpList<T>;
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Definition of class SimpList<T>
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

template < typename T >
class SimpList
{
  public:

    // Constructor (add your code inline)

    SimpList ()
    {
        head = &PHONY;
        length=0;
      // complete the data member intialization
    }

    // Destructor (add your code inline)

    ~SimpList () { clear();}

    // List manipulation operations

    void insert ( const T &newitem );   // insert a data item

    bool remove ( T &item );            // remove data item

    bool find ( T &item ) const;        // find data item

    void clear ();                      // empty the list

    // (add your code inline)
    bool isEmpty () const { 
        if (length == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {   
            return false;
        }
        }

    // length accessor method (add your code inline)
    int size () const { return length; }

    // print the list items
    void print () const;

  private: // data members

    Node<T> PHONY ;      // empty node that anchors the list

    Node<T> *head;      // pointer to the beginning of the list

    int length;         // length of list
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Implementation section
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

template < typename T >
void SimpList<T>::print() const
{
  if (length == 0)
  {
    cout << "List is empty." << endl;
    return;
  }

  Node<T> *ptr=head;
  while (ptr != NULL)
  {

    cout << ptr->value << "  ";
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void SimpList<T>::insert ( const T &newitem )
{
Node<T> *p = new Node<T>;
p->value = newitem;
p->next = head;
head = p;
length++;

}

template <typename T>
void SimpList<T>::clear ()
{

    Node<T> *p = head->next;

    while(p != NULL)
{
    head=head->next;
    delete p;
}

length = 0;

}
template <typename T>
bool SimpList<T>::find ( T &item ) const
{
Node<T> *p;
    for(p=head; p!=NULL; p=p->next)
        if(p->value==item) break;

      if(p!=NULL)
      {
          item=p->value;
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
          return false;
      }


}
template <typename T>
bool SimpList<T>::remove ( T &item )
{
Node<T> *p,*c;

        for(c=head; c!=NULL;p=c,c=c->next)
            if(c->value==item) break;

        if(c!=NULL)
        {
            item=c->value;
            p->next=c->next;
            delete c;
            length --;
            for(c=head;c!=NULL;c=c->next)
            cout<<c->value<<" ";
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;


}
```

The .cpp file is here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "simpList.h"


int main()
{
  SimpList<int> intList;   // (empty) list of integers

  cout << "Let's build a sorted list of integers." << endl;
  cout << endl << "Uninitialized List: ";
  intList.print();
  cout << endl << "Length: " << intList.size() << endl;

  int intData[] = { 5, 3, -2, 7, 9, -8, 1, -4 };

  for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
    intList.insert( intData[i] );
  }
  cout << endl << "After inserting 8 integers: ";
  intList.print();
  cout << endl << "Length: " << intList.size() << endl;

  cout << endl << "--- Testing the \"find\" method:" << endl;

  int t = 5;
  bool ret = intList.find(t);

  cout << endl << t << " is in the list: "
     << (ret ? "true" : "false") << endl;

   t = 6;
  ret = intList.find(t);

 cout << endl << t << " is in the list: "
       << (ret ? "true" : "false") << endl;

  cout << endl << "--- Testing the \"remove\" method:" << endl;

  t = 5;
  ret = intList.remove(t);

  cout << endl << t << " has been removed: "
       << (ret ? "true" : "false") << endl;

  cout << endl << "Remaining list: ";
  intList.print();
  cout << endl << "Length: " << intList.size() << endl;

  cout << endl << "--- Testing the \"clear\" method:" << endl << endl;

  intList.clear();
  intList.print();
  cout << endl << "Length: " << intList.size() << endl;

  cout << endl << "--- Testing the \"isEmpty\" predicate:" << endl;

  cout << endl << "The integer list is now empty: "
       << (intList.isEmpty()? "true" : "false") << endl << endl;

  cout << "Now, let's build a sorted list of strings." << endl;

  string strData[] = { "Maria", "Ann", "Emily", "Vivian",
                       "Beth", "Carla", "Susan" };

  SimpList<string> strList;

  for (int i=0; i<7; i++){
    strList.insert( strData[i] );
  }
  cout << endl << "After inserting 7 names:" << endl;
  strList.print();
  cout << endl << "Length: " << strList.size() << endl;

  cout << endl << "--- Testing the \"remove\" method:" << endl;
  cout << endl << "Bye Carla!" << endl;

  string str = "Carla";
 ret = strList.remove(str);

  cout << endl << str << " has been removed: "
      << (ret ? "true" : "false") << endl;

  cout << endl << "Remaining list:" << endl;
  strList.print();
  cout << endl << "Length: " << strList.size() << endl;

  cout << endl << "--- Testing the \"insert\" method:" << endl;
  cout << endl << "Bienvenue Pauline!" << endl;

  string nom = "Pauline";
  strList.insert(nom);

  cout << endl << "Extended list:" << endl;
  strList.print();
  cout << endl << "Length: " << strList.size() << endl;

  cout << endl << "--- Auf Wiedersehen!" << endl;`enter code here`
  cout << endl << "End of \"main()\"." << endl
       << "At this point, the destructor is called." << endl;


system("PAUSE");}
```

1. FIXED
2. When printing out the items in the list, it prints all items as well as -858993460 and I have exhausted my knowledge of how to fix it.

I would greatly appreciate your guys/gals help or point in the right direction.

Comment: You never actually change `p` (in `clear()`)after it's initial setting, but you are probably deleting it multiple times...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about misusing SO as an online crowd debugging service. **Mentioned to the OP:** Do you have some dangling pointers anywhere? Did you debug and check your pointer values are properly set with every operation. Check this first, and then come back to ask for a particular problem you don't understand!

Comment: The random value in print is the `PHONY` node you have in the list.

Comment: @John3136: thanks, I changed the clear method to a for loop and incremented p=head->next and it works!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That's what I thought it was but I can't figure out how to fix it make it print all the numbers in the list and not the phony...

Comment: You'd have to change the condition to `while (ptr != &PHONY)`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks! It worked! I love this community. Thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you should also change the while loop in `clear()`. You should be getting an error when trying to delete the `PHONY` node, as it is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Think through the logic of the function.  Draw it out as boxes on paper, and work out the order that pointers need to be moved and deleted

Consider this sequence for deleting a linked list.

```
while(there is still an item left in the list)  {
    take a copy of the existing head pointer
    move the head pointer to the next item
    delete the old head using the copy of the head pointer you took before changing it
}
set length to zero
```

Note that in a normal list, the head pointer should be set to zero when the list is empty, and the "next" pointer will be zero on the last item of a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your clear function

```
while(head!=NULL)
```

.   {   node *p = head;
.      head=head->next;
.      delete p
.    }

and also make sure initially head was set to null.otherwise it will take some garbage value during last iteration.

Comment: Thanks, when printing out the list from the cpp file it returns -4, 1, -8, 9, 7, -2, 3, -858993460   any idea why it prints out "-858993460" which I am assuming is my PHONY node?

Comment: Initally you are assigning your head pointer to PHONY node. And it having some address, then when you are building the list in first p->next=head statement you are assigning that PHONY address value to the next of your first node of the linked list, which is not null so it will iterate one more time and will print garbage value. Try initalizing your PHONY to NULL and then assign it to head. It should print fine.